# Passing variables to another page with include

Tags: php

I know there is many question about that but I have a weird situation.

Here is my case, I have a class named Theme and it has a function to include theme parts;

```
class Theme {
  function getThemePart($part, $lang) {
    include_once 'theme/theme.'.$part.'.php';
  }
}
```

And in my index.php page I am calling it;

```
$theme->getThemePart('footer', $lang);
```

It is so normal until here but I also have a $lang variable. I am declaring it in index.php but I am also using it in theme.footer.php file. Like this;

```
<footer class="sticky-footer">
    <div class="container-fluid copyright">
        <span class="float-right"><?=$lang['footer]?><a href="<?=$lang['footer_link]?>" target="_blank"><u><?=$theme->escLang('footer_jc','html')?></u></a></span>
    </div>
</footer>
```

I think you realized that there is a $lang in getThemePart's attributes and it is useless, however, when I remove it, in index.php file $lang['footer'] and $lang['footer_link'] are not printing but when I add that useless $lang variable to getThemePart they are being printed.

How is this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "footer" file *exists only inside the getThemePart function*. As such, it does not "know" anything that was declared outside.

You will notice that even the `{$theme}` object is actually undefined (you might make it work by using `$this` instead).

What you need to do is pass some kind of reference to the "world" or environment that the theme element needs to know (this would be a sort of Dependency Injection):

```
$env  = [ 'lang' => 'en', ... ];
```

You can store it inside the theme:

```
private $env;

public function setEnv($env) {
    $this->env = $env;
}
```

Now if you initialize the theme with `$theme->setEnv($env)`, inside the includes you will be able to call `{$this->env['lang']}`. Or you can build an ancillary function, or maybe even better, declare a [magic getter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get) that would allow you to write `$this->lang`.

Personally, I usually prefer a different approach and replace sequences like `{{name}}` with the content of `$this->env[name]` using `preg_replace_callback()`.